# Compare NSError object against the error code

Tags: objective-c, nserror

I have a ObjC method that is setup like this:

```
- (void) doSomethingWithReply:(void(^)(NSError *))reply
```

I'm calling this method from another class where I have it setup like this:

```
[someObject doSomethingWithReply:^(NSError *error)
                                         {
                                            localerr = error;
                                         }];
```

Ideally I would like to act on based on the return code I receive from my method. For instance, the method `doSomethingWithReply` could return `EACCES` or `EBUSY`. Depending on the return code received, I would like to do something in my calling method. What is the best way to compare `localerr` against `EBUSY` or `EACCESS`?

Using a simple comparison seems to throw an error.

Edit:

Comparison methods I tried:

```
if(localerr == EBUSY)
{
    //do something
}

//Throws the following warning:
//Comparison between pointer and integer ('NSError *' and 'int')
```

```
if(*localerr == EBUSY)
{
    //do something
}
//This throws the follow error:
//Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSError' and 'int')
```

Comment: Where is the comparison part of your code?

Comment: Tip: `NSError` is a class, take a look at it's properties.

Comment: I tried accessing _code, but the compiler complained that it's a private member.
I ended up doing this in the end and this seems to work:

if(localerr == [NSError errorWithDomain:NSPOSIXErrorDomain code:EBUSY userInfo:nil])
{
}

Comment: How about `localerr.code == EBUSY`?